# Php shell command output on to a variable

Tags: php, shell, command, stdout

Hi I'm trying to pass a Shell Command to a variable in php and I'm doing

```
$var=system('ls');
```

and it is executed but the output it is echo as default not in the variable i use to

```
$var=exe('ls');
```

or

```
$var=exec('ls');
```

but print_r just print the last file on the list, why it is happen ?  and how i get to do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

```
$var=shell_exec('ls');
```

or [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
exec('ls', $output, $return_var);

# print array
foreach($output as $content){
  echo $content . "\n";
}
print "return_var:" . $return_var . "\n";
```